# What is the difference between using Align or using Positioned flutter

Tags: layout, dart, flutter, alignment

Her's a concrete example of using both Positionned Widget and Align Widget!
But I had a problem figuring what to use ! though original problem is to set some FABs's Offsets relatively to its Container not to the screen

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(left: 0.0, child: Text("Top\nleft")),
        Positioned(bottom: 0.0, child: Text("Bottom\nleft")),
        Positioned(top: 0.0, right: 0.0, child: Text("Top\nright")),
        Positioned(bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0, child: Text("Bottom\nright")),
        Positioned(bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0, child: Text("Bottom\nright")),
        Positioned(left: width / 2, top: height / 2, child: Text("Center")),
        Positioned(top: height / 2, child: Text("Center\nleft")),
        Positioned(top: height / 2, right: 0.0, child: Text("Center\nright")),
        Positioned(left: width / 2, child: Text("Center\ntop")),
        Positioned(left: width / 2, bottom: 0.0, child: Text("Center\nbottom")),
      ],
    )
    Example #2 (Using Align in Stack)

    Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text("Center"),),
        Align(alignment: Alignment.topRight, child: Text("Top\nRight"),),
        Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text("Center\nRight"),),
        Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomRight, child: Text("Bottom\nRight"),),
        Align(alignment: Alignment.topLeft, child: Text("Top\nLeft"),),
        Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text("Center\nLeft"),),
        Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft, child: Text("Bottom\nLeft"),),
        Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, child: Text("Top\nCenter"),),
        Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: Text("Bottom\nCenter"),),
        Align(alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.5), child: Text("Custom\nPostition", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),),),
      ],
    );

> Blockquot
```

e

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- `Positioned` is an offset based alignment which uses DP as unit
- `Align` use a % of the parent size

As such, `Alignment(0.1, 0.1)` cannot be represented using a `Positioned`. And similarly,`Align` cannot represent a `Positioned(top: 10, left: 10)`.

Secondly, `Positioned` is on a different *flow*.

`Stack` can size itself based on the size of one of its *children* **excluding `Positioned` widgets**.

As such, using an `Align` vs `Positioned` can result in `Stack` taking a different size.

Answer (score 8):

`Positioned` can only be used within a `Stack` and positions a child relative to the `Stack` size.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html

`Align` will be as big as possible within its parent (or a size relative to the children if `heightFactor`, `widthFactor` are passed) and positions its child relative to itself. `Align` can be used everywhere, not only within a `Stack`.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Kind of related but on a slightly different subject,

If anyone comes here looking for a solution to why their widget doesn't precisely align where they put it inside a stack (whether it's Positioned or Align). That is probably caused by some padding value that you're not aware of it's there. Simply, open up dev tools and go through widgets one by one to check if there are any additional spaces.

And on a more rare occasion, if you wrapped one of the top widget tree elements with SafeArea, it also adds padding to both the bottom and the top. It may have been caused by that too. Just a heads up :')